# Django error during collectstatic when using nested_inline on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, static-files, django-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a django app that uses [nested_inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) on a heroku instance. Everything works great locally, but I'm getting an error on the heroku server during collectstatic.

I followed [the heroku guide to getting a minimal django setup working](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction). Then I added "django-nested-inline" to my requirements.txt, added 'nested_inline' to the end of my INSTALLED_APPS, and "from nested_inline.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedStackedInline" to my admin.py.

Everything still works perfectly locally, with no issues. But when I push to heroku "git push heroku master", I get the following error:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 670 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote: Collecting django-nested-inline (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
remote: Downloading django-nested-inline-0.3.6.tar.gz
remote: Installing collected packages: django-nested-inline
remote: Running setup.py install for django-nested-inline: started
remote: Running setup.py install for django-nested-inline: finished with status 'done'
remote: Successfully installed django-nested-inline-0.3.6
remote: 
remote: $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote: Post-processing 'admin/css/forms-nested.css' failed!
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote: File "manage.py", line 10, in 
remote: execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
remote: utility.execute()
remote: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 345, in execute
remote: self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
remote: self.execute(args, *cmd_options)
remote: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
remote: output = self.handle(args, *options)
remote: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
remote: collected = self.collect()
remote: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 128, in collect
remote: raise processed
remote: whitenoise.django.MissingFileError: The file 'admin/img/nav-bg.gif' could not be found with .
remote: The CSS file 'admin/css/forms-nested.css' references a file which could not be found:
remote: admin/img/nav-bg.gif
remote: Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
remote: relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
remote: 
remote: ! Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote: See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote: You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote: Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote: $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
```

As it says, the [forms-nested.css](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline/blob/51260834605e15a79d7ee8b70fa327d0ff805fec/nested_inline/static/admin/css/forms-nested.css) file references images like `nav-bg.gif`, that don't appear to exist anywhere as far as I can tell. But this doesn't stop django and nested_inline from working perfectly fine locally. I'm not sure why it's breaking on heroku?

Answer (score 5):

this is an error that may happen because of `collectstatic` [post-process method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage.post_process).

What you can do is disable heroku to run the `collectstatic` command automatically:

`heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`

And then run collectstatic with [post-process method disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic):

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --no-post-process --noinput
```

If this is not the case then the error might be nested_inline app you installed.